# Is the analog signal or digital signal inside the twisted pair?

Tags: layer2

Is the analog signal or digital signal inside the twisted pair?

In our network, the twisted pair linked to Switch and Hosts. 
I want to know the twisted pair's signal is analog signal or digital signal?

if is analog signal, whether is the Network Adapter for translation the digital signal to analog signal for transfer inside the twisted pair?

Comment: @Zac67 Not that, brother, the fiber is not the same as twisted pair.

Comment: The question is the same whether it's copper or fiber. Light or voltage doesn't matter.

Comment: @qg_java_17137 the signal on twisted pair Ethernet cabling is digital, in the form of square waves.  If fiber optic, it's still digital, with the pulses being light instead of electrical where laser/led <80% is a 1 and laser >20% is a 0.  See the link at the top of the page.  Sure it's analog, technically, but we are looking at thresholds that indicate an on or off state.